# Renaming variable yields different results

Tags: c++, struct

I wrote a simple function which finds the oldest person in an array of structs. The structure stores information about age and name.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
    int age;
    char name[16];
};

char* oldest(Person* arr, int len)
{
    int max = 0;
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    Person elem;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        elem = arr[i];
        if (max < elem.age)
        {
            max = elem.age;
            ptr = arr[i].name;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    Person list[3] = {
        {20, "Alice"},
        {70, "Bob"},
        {25, "James"}
    };
    std::cout << oldest(list, 3) << '\n';
}
```

It yields correct result (namely I see `Bob` on the screen), but when I use `elem` instead of `arr[i]` in the line `ptr = arr[i].name;` (which is nothing but giving another name to `arr[i]`, right??) the program suddenly starts giving some weird results (unprintable characters). I have no idea why it behaves this way.
For your reference, this is the code that doesn't work:

```
char* oldest(Person* arr, int len)
{
    int max = 0;
    char* ptr = nullptr;
    Person elem;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        elem = arr[i];
        if (max < elem.age)
        {
            max = elem.age;
            ptr = elem.name;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: please post the code that has the issue not the one that is fine.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ok

Comment: `Person elem;` is a "copy", you want `/*const*/Person& elem = arr[i];` for an alias.

Comment: `elem = arr[i]` assigs `elem` to be a copy of `arr[i]`.  But `elem` is a local variable, of automatic storage duration, so it (and its contents) cease to exist when the function returns.    If `ptr` points at the (first character of) `elem.name`, the caller receives a dangling reference i.e. a pointer to something that not longer exists.  Dereferencing that  pointer by the caller (e.g. accessing the array, that no longer exists) then gives undefined behaviour.   In comparison, `arr` is passed by the caller, so still exists after the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptr = elem.name;` assigns to `ptr` the address of the first element of `elem.name` (because the arary `elem.name` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element). `elem.name` is of course an array inside `elem`, and `elem` is an object with *automatic storage duration*, meaning it is created automatically in the block it is defined in and it is destroyed when execution of that block terminates. So, when the function return, `elem` ceases to exist in the C++ model of computing, and a pointer to part of it becomes invalid.

> … which is nothing but giving another name to arr[i], right??

No, the statement `elem = arr[i];` makes a copy of `arr[i]` in `elem`. It does not make `elem` an alternate name for `arr[i]`. That copy ceases to exist when the function returns.

If you removed the `Person elem;` declaration and, inside the loop, used `Person &elem = arr[i];` instead of `elem = arr[i];`, that would define `elem` to be a reference to `arr[i]`. Then it would be effectively an alternate name for `arr[i]`, and `ptr = elem.name;` would set `ptr` to point to the first element of `arr[i].name`.

Answer (score 1):

> (which is nothing but giving another name to arr[i], right??)

Not right. `elem` is a distinct object. It is not a name of `arr[i]`.

> but when I use elem instead of arr[i] in the line ptr = arr[i].name; ... the program suddenly starts giving some weird results

With that change, you are returning a pointer to (a member of) an automatic variable. When the function returns, the automatic variable is destroyed and the returned pointer will be invalid. When you indirect through the invalid pointer and attempt to access deallocated memory, the beahviour of the program is undefined.